# Redirect to subpage of https

Tags: http, redirect, https, url-rewriting

When I try to go to http://www.example.com/site1

it takes me to

https://www.example.com/index.php

How do I make it go to https://www.example.com/site1 straight away?

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: It's not related to this rule.

Comment: You should have other rules in the https-related configuration files. Please share those, you may have a redirect that forces all the http pages to go to https